# layoutIfNeeded causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have a UITextView, that is displaying text
When the text is not very large(i'm speaking about 100-200 words), the app is working just fine

If it has EXTREMLY large texts(around 10000 words), it keeps crashing

The code

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    check(scrollView)
    let scrollPos = textView.contentOffset.y

    if dragging { return }
    if isAppearanceOpened { return }

    if scrollPos > 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            if scrollPos <= self.contentOffset {
                self.topView.alpha = 1
                self.pageView.alpha = 1
                self.topViewHeight.constant = 70
            } else {
                self.topView.alpha = 0
                self.pageView.alpha = 0
                self.topViewHeight.constant = 0
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (_) in
            if !decelerate { self.recheckEditorPosition() }
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.topView.alpha = 1
            self.pageView.alpha = 1
            self.topViewHeight.constant = 70
        }) { (_) in
            if !decelerate { self.recheckEditorPosition() }
        }
    }
}
```

The error

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d2a7ef0)

Console is clear, so i'm kind of confused
If i'm removing `self.view.layoutIfNeedee()`, the app works just fine, but the animation is absent

Comment: How often does the code get executed within a large text view?

Comment: @InfinityJames quite often, so it's really important

Answer (score 2):

So, i got a result out of my research
The crash was caused by the textView contentInset.
When the left and right insets are 0, it's working well on large texts, and my guess is that the calculation of the textView alignements, fonts, and so on are quite time consuming, so the compiler just gave a error.

Comment: How did you salve it?